# Get error when inserting web part to page

Tags: web-part

We're implementing a custom web part (based on this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ramg/archive/2009/04/21/implementing-a-simple-cross-site-collection-list-view-webpart.aspx)) but it throws this error when trying to insert it into the page:

```
A Web Part or Web Form Control on this Page cannot be displayed or imported, 
the type could not be found or it is not registered as safe.
```

We created an Empty SharePoint project, added a Web Part Item, copied code from the article, and commented out the GUID. I can post the code of the one *.CS file but didn't want to unless it's useful.

We've followed the instructions in this [post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22736/custom-web-part-throws-error-when-i-try-to-add-it-to-page). We have the following in the web.config file for this web part:

```
<SafeControl 
  Assembly="CustomListWeBPart, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f85e54975c551557" 
  Namespace="CustomListWeBPart.CustomListWebPart" TypeName="*" 
  Safe="True" SafeAgainstScript="False" />
```

What are we doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Post the .webpart file, I'll bet the type name is wrong (doesn't match the safecontrol).

Comment: Thanks, James. I think that was it. We did a fresh VS project and the problem went away.

Comment: Common problem. Always check the .webpart file, then the namespace and class name in the .cs file, and finally click the webpart Folder in the VS Solution, hit F4 to bring up the properties panel, and look athe SafeControls entries to make sure it all matches up. I often rename the namespaces in new webparts so I check all of these when I do.

Comment: Thanks, James. If you provide the above as an answer I'll mark it as the correct one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common problem. Always check the .webpart file, then the namespace and class name in the .cs file, and finally click the webpart Folder in the VS Solution, hit F4 to bring up the properties panel, and look athe SafeControls entries to make sure it all matches up. I often rename the namespaces in new webparts so I check all of these when I do.